# Jquery can't see anchor tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My JQUERY can't see echo PHP.

Here is the php statement that I `echo` in an external PHP file -

```
 `echo ("<a href='#' id='bb'>hello</a>");
```

Here is the JQUERY also in an external js file -

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var linkId;
    linkId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(linkId);`
```

And finally I have an HTML file with a `<div>` that my php is being sent to via ajax.
Now my php echo statement above shows in the HTML file, but when I click it the JQUERY      doesn't see it. I tested it by adding an anchor tag in the html file and it works fine. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks`enter code here`

Comment: You're going to have to explain this a bit more. Can you add more example code?

Comment: it's because you only bind handler on the click event for those anchors presented on the document at the moment of binding.

Comment: @Gavin OK I will post it now

Comment: As @Cthulhu says, you need [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Something like `$(document).on('click', 'a', function()...`.

Comment: Just a guess `$(function () { ... });` wrap it in a document ready handler or delegate it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#parentID').on('click','a' , function(){
    var linkId;
    linkId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(linkId);`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is not complete. You are not closing the function call. A jQuery click function call needs to be like `$('#element').click(function() { ... });

Also, you are not preventing the default link behavior from happening, so your page will refresh. I don't think you want the page to refresh, right? You need to capture the click event and stop it using `preventDefault();`

So the script should be:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    var linkId;
    linkId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(linkId);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```